# Can't activate Job in sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint

this code is an error in the line `oJob.Update();`

```
string JOB_NAME = "TestJob";
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite("http://mysite", SPUserToken.SystemAccount))
{
NotifyJob oJob = new NotifyJob(JOB_NAME, oSite.WebApplication);
SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
schedule.EndSecond = 59;
schedule.Interval = 30;
oJob.Schedule = schedule;
oSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
oJob.Update();
});
oSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}



Error: System.Security.SecurityException: Access denied.
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate()
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPJobDefinition.Update()
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please check if this solution applies to your scenario. From your code i'm guessing that your executing it from some kind of webpart/page.

http://unclepaul84.blogspot.com/2010/06/sppersistedobject-xxxxxxxxxxx-could-not.html

Second thing is that `RunWithEvelatedPrivileges` executes code under Application Pool identity. If you are executing it from normal SharePoint content site collection, which is running on different app pool (and account - which how it should be) then Central Administration, you still may not have access to Timer Job, which requires Farm Administrator rights.

Comment: I have Farm Administrator rights, this code from ApplicationPage, when i try activate empty Feature in sharepoint than it's ok, but when i activate Feature with EventResiever, Feature goes to error/

Comment: If the feature in question is a web/site feature, you'll need to activate it via powershell on a farm machine rather than through the UI on a remote client, due to the reasons in Marek's link. (Or you can deactivate the security feature as in that link, but only as a global setting, so I wouldn't recommend it.)

Answer (score 0):

don't obtain site or web from SPSite/SPWeb constuctor. 
you should take it from SPFeatureReceiverProperties

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
    NotifyJob oJob = new NotifyJob("TestJob", web.Site.WebApplication);
    SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
    schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
    schedule.EndSecond = 59;
    schedule.Interval = 30;
    oJob.Schedule = schedule;
    oJob.Update();
}
```

or

```
SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
```

if your feature scope is Site

Comment: yes. i use multiserver farm. Wsp is installed, but when try activate feature goes this error.  Error in deployment step 'Activate components ": Component ID" 951904dc-c26a-4a83-95c2-xxxxx "not installed in this farm, and can not be added to this area.